# PDO using wrong remote host name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use the database in remote hosting using PHP PDO.
I need to access the database on `b.com` from `a.com`.
`a.com` was allowed on `b.com` on cPanel.

When I run the following code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=b.com;dbname=dbtest;charset=utf8;port=3306", "b_root", "toor");
```

The error went out as follows.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'b_root'@'my.hostingservice.com' (using password: YES)' in /home...

Although the host expresses `b.com`, the user is looking for `my.hostingservice.com`.
Can you help?

Comment: Your PDO is connecting to b.com. The authentication is against the user b_root@my.hostingservice.com. I think your hosting provider should be able to give proper instructions on connecting to their database. Its hard to know what cpanel allowing between sites means in a database sense.

Comment: The PDO statement is right. Check your hosting provider how to make a database connection to remote hosts. Maybe they forward requests to port 3306 to their own database server, or something like this... Another thing: if you can use real data (like the real name of your hosting service), people can be more specific in helping you.

Comment: The `@hostname` part of the username is where you user is logging in **from**. That's how MySQL users work